# Why is the controller for a view loaded twice?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

Please check [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/r0QfW4sod00xjrclWtQu?p=preview) for the issue I am explaining below.

When you run the plunk you will observe that there are certain tabs. The first tab `Home` belongs to `home` state. The remaining tabs belong to `category` state each tab identified by a category ID.

When I am currently on `Home` tab and I click on some other tab, the `CategoriesController` is invoked just once as expected. But when I click on some other tab from there the `CategoriesController` is invoked multiple times, once for the previous tab and twice for the newly selected tab. Please run the plunker and observer the browser console to better understand it.

I do not know why the controller is invoked for the previous tab also. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not sure about the reason of invoking controllers multiple times. I'm trying to figure out the problem but till then you can do the following:</strike>

1. Remove `controller: "CategoriesController"` from the state configuration
2. Add `ng-controller="CategoriesController"` to the `ui-view="categories"` element

This will work for now since only that view -> controller will be invoked which is active.

**Edit:**

Got the problem, you have the `ui-view="categories"` in each tab so `n` number of `ui-view` are being rendered for `n` number of your tabs.

Now what is actually happening, to provide the slide animation, Angular material is keeping the left and right tab available in the DOM as well.

So when you are clicking from Home (i.e. first tab) to another tab, it's working fine. But when you are going from any other tab (other than 1st tab), it's respective left & right tab are coming into action as well since the sliding effect needs to be performed.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to work. I need to click on a tab twice to activate it.

Comment: Why do you want to use state for tabs? Why can't you use simple directive?

Answer (score 0):

U are changing `seletedTab` value in your `CategoriesController` and `$stateChangeStart` $watcher.but at the same time u are using `ui-view` with `ng-if` which need the `seletedTab` as a parameter.

Say currently u are on tab 0, and switching to tab 1. And Things happens like this:

1. First of all, ur state change start.In the `$stateChangeStart` watcher, the `selectedTab` is set to 1.
2. The `ui-view` in tab 0 is removed from DOM.
3. The `ui-view` in tab 1 is added to DOM, but currently the $stateParams.catID is still 0.In this way, it initiated the `CategoriesController` with $stateParams.catID = 0. And at the same time, it set the `seletedTab` to 0. **This is the first invoke for previous Controller**
4. The `ui-view` in tab 1 is removed from DOM and `ui-view` in tab 0 is added to DOM.
5. Then ur $state changed successfully. The `ui-view` in tab 0 inited the `CategoriesController` with $stateParams.catID = 1 and set the `seletedTab` to 1.**This is the first invoke for next Controller**
6. OK now the `ui-view` in tab 0 is removed and the `ui-view` in tab 1 is added to DOM again and finally inited the `CategoriesController` with $stateParams.catID = 1. Everything looks OK though. **This is the second invoke for next Controller**

Hope i made it clear.